# What's the point of Shadow Kill?

Tags: dishonored

If killing with [Shadow Kill](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Kill) still raises the chaos level then what's the point of Shadow Kill?

Does it produce less chaos then leaving a body lying around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to play Dishonored, if you are playing by killing and still remaining hidden shadow kill is a useful skill as you don't have to take care of the bodies which can tip off enemies.

As to your second question, a body being found also produces chaos in addition to that of killing.

Comment: This is very helpful. I was initially playing the low chaos route so I thought I wasn't allowed to kill anybody, but sneaky assassin route seems like much more fun.

Comment: Does this mean if you shadow kill then it won't ever alert the guards of your presence?

Comment: If you get seen killing someone then the guards will be alerted, but the ash will not count as being spotted.

Comment: Bear in mind it also *looks badass.*